# Looping through sheets finding values and saving them values on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet which has many different sheets which is growing and reducing all the time.

There will be multiple sheets that look identical but with different data.

- Cell `C1` holds a date
- Column `A` holds record id
- Column `B` holds a percentage

I need to save the % against the record id and create a column with the date as a heading in a separate sheet.

If the date already exists, I need to overwrite the data in that column with the new data in the different sheets. The date will be consistent across all spreadsheets.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't assume that I just give you all the code for that. You should begin with doing something like this.

```
Dim ids() As Integer
Dim percentages() As String
Dim strDate As Date
Dim sheetName As String

x = Sheets.Count

For i = x To 1 Step -1
    ReDim Preserve ids(i)
    ReDim Preserve percentages(i)

    sheetName = YourSheet & i
    date = sheetName.Range("C1").Value
    ids(i) = sheetName.Range("A" & i).Value
    percentages(i) = sheetName.Range("B" & i).Value
Next i
```

And then put it all in a new Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up writing to perform my function. The cells where I was reading the data changed, I've also left in the code where I made mistakes. If anyone would like to make comments on how it could be improved I would welcome them as I am new to this

```
Sub SavePercentage()
Dim ids(10000) As Long
Dim Percentages(10000) As String
Dim MEDate As Date
Dim sheetName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim n As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim DateCol As Long
'Dim DCol As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim lastrow As Range
Dim Percent As Worksheet
Dim v As Variant
Dim FindRange As Range
Dim ra As Range
Dim IDRow As Long
Dim Findcell As Range



x = Sheets.Count
n = 0

For i = 1 To 3
    Set Sht = Sheets(i)

    If Sht.Name <> "Options" And _
        Sht.Name <> "PercentageComplete" And _
        Sht.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

        'Debug.Print Sht.Name

        MEDate = Sht.Range("C3").Value
        Debug.Print MEDate
        r = 8
        Do While Sht.Cells(r, 6) <> ""
            n = n + 1
            If n > 10000 Then
                MsgBox "Plot Array size exceeded"
                Exit Do
            End If

            ids(n) = Sht.Cells(r, 6)
            Percentages(n) = Sht.Cells(r, 20)
            r = r + 1
            'Debug.Print ids(n), Percentages(n)
        Loop
    End If
Next i
```

---

```
Set Sht = ActiveSheet
Set Percent = Worksheets("percentagecomplete")
Percent.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Percent.Activate
For Each FindRange In [2:2]
    If FindRange.Value = MEDate Then
        DateCol = FindRange.Column
    End If
Next


    If DateCol = 0 Then
            For Each FindRange In [2:2]
                If FindRange.Column > 1 Then
                    If FindRange.Value = 0 Then
                        DateCol = FindRange.Column
                        'Debug.Print DateCol
                        Percent.Cells(2, DateCol).Value = MEDate
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
    End If
Set FindRange = Percent.Range("b2:b10000")

For i = 1 To 10000
    If ids(i) = 0 Then Exit For
    'Debug.Print ids(i)
    'For Each FindRange In ("b1:b10000")
    For Each Findcell In FindRange.Cells
        If Findcell.Value = 0 Then Exit For

                If Findcell.Value = ids(i) Then
                'Debug.Print findcell.Value
                    IDRow = Findcell.Row
                    Exit For
                Else
                    IDRow = 0
                End If

    Next

    If IDRow = 0 Then
        'For Each FindRange In [b:b]
        For Each Findcell In FindRange.Cells
            'If FindRange.Row > 1 Then
                If Findcell.Value = 0 Then
                    IDRow = Findcell.Row
                    'Debug.Print IDRow
                    Percent.Cells(IDRow, 2).Value = ids(i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            'End If
        Next
    End If

    Percent.Cells(IDRow, DateCol).Value = Percentages(i)



Next

Percent.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sht.Activate
```

End Sub